# Как изменить объект, переданный как параметр функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как передать функции параметр, чтобы при изменении внутри он менялся фактически, то есть как в плюсах

```
void do(int &x) {
    x = 1;
}
```

Comment: Числа — никак, они по определению неизменяемы, только оборачивать в какой-нибудь изменяемый объект

Comment: related: [In Python, why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/575196/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Python все объекты передаются по ссылке, но изменить значение (внутреннее содержимое), передав объект через параметры, можно только у изменяемых объектов (например, списков/множеств/словарей или кастомных классов). Можно создать класс-контейнер, будет что-то вроде этого:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

def do(container):
    container.x = 1

xx = Container(0)
print(xx.x)
do(xx)
print(xx.x)
```

В первом случае `print` выведет `0` (которым объект был проинициализирован), во втором - `1`, которая была записана в объект в функции.

Естественно, просто для целого числа так никто не будет делать. Если же нужно передавать сложный класс, то скорее всего и функция `do` должна быть методом этого класса (хотя, все зависит от конкретной задачи).

В качестве варианта решения, можно просто возвращать обновленное значение:

```
def do(x):
    return x + 1

x = 0
x = do(x)
print(x)  # 1
```

Для стандартных "контейнерных" типов все проще, можно просто поменять содержимое переданного в функцию контейнера:

```
def do(x):
    x.append(1)  # предполагаем, что x - список

x = []
do(x)
print(x)  # выведет [1]
```

Но все равно нельзя поменять один список на совершенно другой, например, вот это не сработает:

```
def do(x):
    x = [1]

x = []
do(x)
print(x)  # выведет []
```

Comment: 1- В целом правильно, но *"передаются по ссылке"* слишком перегруженная (и сложная) терминология (в разных языках это немного разные вещи означает (Java/C++/Rust)). В Питоне достаточно знать об именах и соответствующих объектах и всё. 2- В качестве легковесного хака вместо создания специального объекта вроде `Container`, можно просто список с одним элементом передать: `def foo(bar): bar[0] = 1` (к примеру так [nonlocal на Питоне 2 можно эмулировать](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python#comment27954130_141426)).

Comment: @jfs, про данный хак я думал, но посчитал, что лучше не учить плохому )

Comment: тогда уж следует `do` в метод `Container` превратить `def do(self): self.x = 1`, если `bar = [x]` слишком "грязный" хак. И явно упомянуть, что `do` является плохим именем и вообще выбросить `do` и просто использовать `container.x = 1` напрямую.

Comment: @jfs, про то, что в более сложных случаях стоит делать функцию сразу методом контейнера я упомянул, но не стал расширять. По поводу "выбросить do" - вопрос был все-таки про передачу значений в функцию/из функции, так что если убрать do, то и вопроса такого не будет. Но все зависит от того, какую задачу пытается решить автор.

Answer (score -1):

Кратко: никак.

В Python нет возможности работать с объектами напрямую, т.к. есть изменяемость\неизменяемость объекта. В данном случае встроенные числа не могут быть изменены, но с их помощью могут быть созданы другие объекты с новым значением.

/Offtop:
Python это Python, а C++ это C++. Каждому языку свои способы решения задач. Если Вас не устраивает то как решаются задачи с помощью Python, то и неследует его использовать. Есть же другие языки для разработки.

Comment: [ответ, который показывает как работать с объектами напрямую и изменить "встроенные числа"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044) (нужно ли говорить, что если что-то *можно* сделать, это ещё не значит, что это *следует* делать)