# Присваивание целых (int) в Питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Допустим, есть следующий код:

```
a = 32
b = a

print(a is b)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы b становилось ссылкой на новое значение в памяти, а не на то значение, на которое ссылается a, т.е. как сделать так, чтобы операция `print(a is b)` напечатала `False`?

Comment: связанный вопрос: ['is' operator behaves unexpectedly with non-cached integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34147515/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`b = a` заставляет `b` имя ссылаться на тот же объект что и `a` имя.

Операция `a is b` проверяет указывают ли оба имени на один и тот же объект, поэтому всегда всегда `a is b` будет `True` после `a = b` в Питоне.

Если вы хотите, чтобы имя `b` ссылалось на объект отличный от `a`, то просто присвойте любой другой объект, например, `b = None` для примера в вопросе или можно вообще удалить имя `del b` (при попытке использования после этого исключение возникнет).

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы `a` и `b` были равны (`a == b == 32`), но были бы разными объектами (`a is not b`), то ответ может зависеть от конкретной реализации Питона.

Например, [в CPython маленькие целые числа кэшируются](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) поэтому `32 is (16*2) is (31+1)`... то есть существует только *один* объект, который представляет число `32` в СPython. Целые числа неизменяемы в Питоне, поэтому арифметика не изменится от того один и тот же объект для `32` возвращается каждый раз или разные.

Нужно обратить внимание, что **не следует оператор `is` использовать для сравнения чисел.** Так как *разные* объекты могут иметь одно значение (быть равными), например, `1000 == (999+1)`, но `1000 is not (999+1)` (в данном случае `(999+1)` возвращает *новый* объект, отличный от объекта, созданного для `1000` константы). `is` можно использовать для сравнения с singleton—объект, который в единственном экземпляре существует, такой как `None`. Питон не обещает, что объекты, представляющие числа, существуют в единственном экземпляре, поэтому **используйте `==` для сравнения целых чисел.**

---

Есть несколько решений буквальной задачи (`a == b == 32 and a is not b`), если её рассматривать как загадку (не для использования на практике).

Чтобы обойти кэширование маленьких чисел, можно создать производный от `int` класс:

```
>>> a = 32
>>> class Int(int):
...     pass
...     
>>> b = Int(a)
>>> a == b == 32 and a is not b
True
```

Или использовать `float` или любой другой тип, который можно с целыми сравнивать:

```
>>> b = 32.
>>> a == b == 32 and a is not b
True
```

Наконец, если вы хотите, чтобы `type(a) == type(b) == int`, где `int` это встроенный `PyLongObject` тип, то возможно сделать злую вещь и поменять значение известной константы `42`:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> import sys
>>> a = 32
>>> b = 42
>>> (ctypes.c_ubyte * sys.getsizeof(b)).from_address(id(b))[-4] = a
>>> a == b == 32 and a is not b
True
>>> type(a) == type(b) == int
True
>>> (32 + 10) == 32
True
```

- `id(b)` возвращает адрес объекта в памяти, представляющего `42`, в CPython
- `sys.getsizeof(b)` возвращает размер объекта `b` в байтах
- `(ctypes.c_ubyte * sys.getsizeof(b))` задаёт тип массива байтов, который может вместить `b` объект (`unsigned char[28]`)
- `.from_address()` создаёт массив из памяти, начиная с адреса, где `b` объект расположен
- `arr[-4] = a` присваивает четвёртому с конца байту значение `32`. Что имеет эффект изменения константы `42` (связано с тем [как `_longobject` в памяти представлен (единственная цифра/digit меняется)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b3fe61c553544d707a144a90f9e65b144ce2f59/Include/longintrepr.h#L70-L88), в частности это говорит, что `python3` команда использует `PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT == 30` , что `sys.int_info` подтверждает и порядок байтов от младшего к старшему на моей машине, что `sys.byteorder` также подтверждает).

Код был вдохновлён статьёй: [«...Как избавиться от коллеги, пишущего на Питоне»](https://lameiro.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/deixando-o-interpretador-python-maluco/).

Answer (score 1):

Присваивание всегда выделяет новую область в памяти, если речь идёт не о коллекциях.

Но в данном случае речь идёт об оптимизации производительности языка, ведь данное число наверняка не только вы решили использовать :)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(32)
70
>>> n = 32
>>> sys.getrefcount(32)
71

>>> a = 32
>>> b = 32
>>> a is b
True
```

Вот ещё пример с коллекцией:

```
>>> a = "asdf"
>>> b = "asdf"
>>> a is b
True
```

Но если выбрать число побольше, то область в памяти уже будет разная, потому как это число видимо программой не используется:

```
>>> a = 1000000
>>> b = 1000000
>>> a is b
False
```

Поэтому если проверять числа, то нужно обязательно использовать сравнение `==`.

Comment: нет, присваивание `b = a` всегда заставляет имя `b` указывать *на тот же объект* что и `a` имя. Вне зависимости от реализации/оптимизации Питона.

Answer (score -2):

Можно попробовать так:

```
a=[1]
b=[1]
print (a is b)
```