# Сравнение значения ID в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему в Python3 при сравнение идентификатора с самим собой получается False.

```
id(False)
=> 140076979909600

id(False) is id(False)
=> False

id(False) == id(False)
=> True

x = id(False)
print(x)
139746282587104

x is x
=> True

False is x
=> False

id(False) is x
=> False

id(False) is id(x)
=> False

print(x, id(False))
139746282587104 139746282587104

type(id(False)) is type(id(False))
=> True

type(id(False))
=> <class 'int'>
```

Идентификатор не меняется, тип не меняется.

Comment: разные объекты - разные идентификаторы

Comment: `id(False) is id(False)`, идентификатор это внутренняя ссылка на объект, каждый раз вызывая `id()`, похоже, создается новый объект типа `int`, который хранит значение идентификатора, поэтому сравнивать через `is` не хорошо, используйте тогда оператор `==`, который сравнит по значению. `type(id(False)) is type(id(False))` равны, потому что `type(id(False))` вернет тип `int`, а у каждого типа идентификатор уникальный и неповторимый

Comment: @slippyk объект не меняется, мы сравниваем его с самим собой

Comment: @gil9red но как он может создавать ещё один объект False. Значения id   одинаковы, если бы он создавал другой объект, то при сравнение False is False получалось False, но это не так.

Comment: @Aivengo, не `False` новый создается, а при `id(False)` создается новый объект типа `int`, который из `id(False)` возвращается

Comment: @gil9red я не совсем понимаю работу оператора is. При сравнивание объектов id(False) is id(False), сравниваются уже существующие объекты в памяти или функция id создаёт новый объект?

Comment: @Aivengo, `id(False)` возвращает значение идентификатора `False`, например `123456` (тип `int`), а `123456` это объект со своими методами и свойствами и у него тоже есть идентификатор и делая `id(False) is id(False)` сравниваются не идентификаторы `False`. Понятно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id()` возвращает число (`int`). Равные числа (`==`) не обязаны быть представлены одним и тем же объектом (`is`).

Иначе говоря: `id(a) == id(а)` (так как `a is a`), но из равенства значений (что `id` функция возвращает), не следует идентичность `int` объектов.

Подробнее, посмотрите связанный (обратный) вопрос: [Что такое объект в Python. Почему id(a) == id(b) == id(1)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662398/23044) и ещё о работе `is`,  `==` для целых чисел в Питоне: [Присваивание в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044).

Кратко:

- **не следует оператор `is` использовать для сравнения чисел**
- **используйте `==` для сравнения целых чисел**.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим, что вы делаете:

```
# Смотрим идентификатор объекта (число)
id(False)  
=> 139746282587104

# Записываем в переменную идентификатор объекта (число)
x = id(False)  
print(x)
=> 139746282587104

# Сравниваем идентификатор объекта сам с собой как объект.
# Смысл данного действия не очень понятен.
x is x  
=> True

# Сравниваем объект False и число (идентификатор объекта), что не имеет смысла.
False is x  
=> False

# Сравниваем идентификатор объекта (число) и идентификатор объекта в переменной (число) как объекты.
# Равенство объектов для одинаковых по значению чисел не гарантируется.
id(False) is x  
=> False

# Сравниваем идентификатор объекта False и идентификатор идентификатора объекта False как объекты.
# Данное сравнение не имеет смысла.
id(False) is id(x)  
=> False
```

Имеет смысл сравнивать `id` объектов по равенству или сравнивать сами объекты через `is`, но сравнивать идентификаторы идентификаторов по равенству значений или сравнивать идентификаторы через `is`, или идентификатор объекта с самим объектом - не имеет смысла.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, а в чем смысл проверять `False is x`, если `x = id(False)`? Это же разные объекты... `id(False)` вернет тип `int`, а у `False`, конечно будет и другой тип, и другой `id`. Да и `id(x)` это `id(id(False))`. Непонятные мне эти манипуляции и чего вы хотели ими показать

Comment: @gil9red, ох блин, затупил.

Comment: @insolor почему при сравнение  id(False) is x равенство  не гарантируется?  Сравнивая одинаковые объекты id(False) is id(False), объект не меняется как и его значения.

Comment: @Aivengo, если объекты одинаковые по значению, это еще не означает, что это один и тот же объект. Насколько я помню, целые числа до 256 включительно все существуют в единственном экземпляре, а вот `257 is (257-1+1)` вам вернет `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Идентификаторы как раз и меняются.

> **is** возвращает истину, если оба операнда указывают на один объект.

```
x = id(False)
```

Здесь будет создана переменная (объект) `x` с новым идентификатором, отличным от `id(False)`, но с присвоенным значением идентификатора `False`.

То есть:

```
id(False) is id(x)
>>>> False
id(False) == id(x)
>>>> False
id(False) is x
>>>> False
```

Но:

```
x == id(False)
>>>> True
```

Comment: Спасибо, с x = id(False) разобрался, это разные объекты с схожими значениями. Но почему id(False) is id(False)
выходит False?

Comment: вероятно значения, возвращаемые вызовом `id()` хранятся в разных местах (адресах памяти), поэтому `id(False) is id(False)` дает результат `False`, хотя значения одинаковы `id(False) == id(False)` - `True`

Comment: то есть `id(False)` сохраняет значение в свою ячейку памяти, второй вызов `id(False)` сохраняет значение в еще одну ячейку. Т.к. оператор `is` сравнивает объекты, то и получается `False`, так как объекты (адреса) разные

Answer (score 0):

```
# 1==3 создаст ссылку  и свяжет её с 
переменной x возвращаемое 
значение типа bool
x = 1==3
# преобразует 0 к типу bool 0>>False 
1>>True
b = bool(0)
# сравниваем значения ссылок
x is b
True
# возвращаемые значения
b, x
(False, False)
# ну и айди
id(b); id(x)
3069765112
3069765112
```

Объекты True и False вобщем всегда будут иметь одни айди т.к. они всегда живут в памяти вроде как то так.:)