# Вопрос по методу reverse() в python

Tags: python

Есть такая последовательность команд:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = a
>>> b.reverse()
>>> a
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> b
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

Почему список `a` тоже переворачивается вместе с `b`?

Ведь по нормальной человеческой логике `a` должен остаться в прежнем значении

Comment: Уже ответили почему и как, а я добавлю пример копирования списка: `b = list(a)` (есть еще модуль `copy`, который на такое заточен)

Comment: Связанные вопросы [Присваивание в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044) и [Что такое объект в Python. Почему id(a) == id(b) == id(1)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662398/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что списки в Python - это объекты. И код `b=a` в случае, если `a` - объект, означает, что `b` будет указывать на ту же область памяти, что и `a`.

Answer (score 3):

Операция `b = a` не копирует список, а просто после нее две переменных указывают на один и тот же объект (это можно проверить с помощью оператора `is`: выражение `a is b` вернет `True`, т.е. объекты совпадают). После реверса в обеих переменных видим один и тот же инвертированный список.

Если нужно получить инвертированную копию списка в другой переменной, то можно воспользоваться функцией `reversed()`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]

>>> b = list(reversed(a))

>>> b
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Вызов `list()` нужен для того, чтобы итератор, возвращенный функцией `reversed()` превратить в список.

Comment: Стоит a is b упомянуть

Answer (score 0):

для создания копии объекта используйте:

```
b = a[:]
```

или

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```