# Указатель/ссылка на область памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, ссылки, адрес

Здравствуйте, постараюсь максимально подробно описать суть проблемы:

Почти год программирую на Python 3, потребовалось использовать указатель на переменную, которая может являться как изменяемой (mutable), например `list`, так и неизменяемой (immutable), например `float`.

Требуется используя адрес переменной "A" записать адрес в переменную "B", таким образом, чтобы после изменения "A", через переменную "B" можно было узнать значение в "A".

Пример на С/C++:

```
int A=0;
int *B;
B=&A;
printf("%d\n", *B); //ответ: 0
A=1;
printf("%d\n", *B); //ответ: 1
```

Пытаюсь реализовать на Python и написать функцию, которая принимает два элемента, например "element" и "under_element", где "element" типа список (list), "under_element" любой объект (`float`, `str`, `list`, "мой_объект").

Функция записывает адрес объекта "under_element", в один из элементов списка "element" так, что при изменении "under_element" используя объект "element" можно было бы узнать актуальное значение "under_element"

Пример структуры функции на Python 3 ("укороченный"):

```
def f(element, under_element, i=0):
    print("depth=", i, "\tfs_element=", element)
    if(i<1):
        f(element[0], under_element, i+1)
    else:
        element=under_element
    print("depth=", i, "\tff_element=", element)

element=[[0],[1]]
under_element='str'
print("start_element=", element, "\n")

f(element, under_element)

under_element='list'
print("\nfinish_element=", element)
```

Результат работы программы:

```
start_element= [[0], [1]] 

depth= 0    fs_element= [[0], [1]]
depth= 1    fs_element= [0]
depth= 1    ff_element= str
depth= 0    ff_element= [[0], [1]]

finish_element= [[0], [1]]
```

Желаемый результат работы программы:

```
start_element= [[0], [1]] 

depth= 0    fs_element= [[0], [1]]
depth= 1    fs_element= [0]
depth= 1    ff_element= str
depth= 0    ff_element= ['str', [1]]

finish_element= ['list', [1]]
```

Нашел решение состоящее из четырех пунктов:

1. все элементы заключать в `list`, пример: `under_element=['str']`
2. передавать в функцию переменные в виде лист
3. обращаться к записываемому объекту без дополнительных `[]` (без указания глубины)
4. обращаться к объекту, в который записываем с дополнительным `[]` (с указанием глубины)

Пример переделанной функции:

```
def f(element, under_element, i=0):
    print("depth=", i, "\tfs_element=", element)
    if(i<1):
        f(element[0], under_element, i+1)
    else:
        element[0]=under_element
    print("depth=", i, "\tff_element=", element)

element=[[0],[1]]
under_element=['str']
print("start_element=", element, "\n")

f(element, under_element)

under_element[0]='list'
print("\nfinish_element=", element)
```

Результат работы программы:

```
start_element= [[0], [1]] 

depth= 0    fs_element= [[0], [1]]
depth= 1    fs_element= [0]
depth= 1    ff_element= [['str']]
depth= 0    ff_element= [[['str']], [1]]

finish_element= [[['list']], [1]]
```

Недостатки данного решения:

1. мусор в массивах и коде программы
2. нет гарантии, что пользователь функции пользуется переменными, как указано выше к данному примеру, и не передаст объект являющийся immutable (`float`, `str` и др.)

Повторюсь:

Требуется обратиться к объекту (1) через другой объект (2), например через элемент списка, или чтобы значение объекта (1) было в объект (2), даже после изменения объекта (1), другими словами всегда соответствовало значению объекта(1)

Пример:

```
A=0
```

запоминаем адрес в "B"

```
А=1
```

смотрим на "А" через "B" получаем 1

(после записи адреса "A" в "B", нельзя обратиться к "A", но требуется взять значение "А", которое в нее записано)

Comment: В питоне нет указателей. Вы пытаетесь тащить понятия и подходы из C/С++ туда, где они вообще неприменимы. Из вашего вопроса я вообще не понял, какая у вас конечная задача, но я более чем уверен, что она решается совсем не так.

Comment: Задача записать в список элемент так, чтобы последующие изменения этого элемента можно было увидеть через элемент списка, в который я его записал. Теоретически это поможет оптимизировать код, т.к. мне не придется искать элементы, которые я записал, проверяя все элементы в списке, т.к. я смогу сразу обращаться к нему, количество элементов произвольное количество и зависит от предустановок

Comment: Ещё раз: вы не можете работать с питоном так, как привыкли в C/C++. Тут совершенно другие механизмы управления памятью, и вы не можете обращаться к адресам напрямую.

Comment: Возможно, есть другой способ решить данную проблему?

Comment: Не совсем понятна ваша проблема. Вы привели пример на Си, который можно повторить с помощью `ctypes` в `python`, а потом приводите какие-то примеры, которые делают совсем другое.

Comment: Пишите на C/C++/Go. Питон специально создавался для того, чтобы можно было работать на более высоком уровне абстракции, и не лезть в память напрямую.

Comment: Получить адрес элемента можно методом 'id()' но в Python это абсолютно бессмысленное дело.

Comment: mkkik, спасибо за предложенную библиотеку, к сожалению я не могу сказать подойдет ли данная библиотека, так как не работал с ней, возможность написать часть участков программы на С может подойти, я все еще надеюсь, что есть способ проще )

Comment: Александр, у меня есть написанный код, с использованием библиотек Python, также я не изучал GO, и боюсь, что часть библиотек Python может отсутствовать

Comment: Игорь Игоряныч, находил несколько сайтов, в которых через id() получают элемент находящийся по адресу, с помощью сочетания функций: id(), ctypes.string_at(), struct.unpack_from привожу сайты: (https://habrahabr.ru/post/193890/) и (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html"), к сожалению данный набор функций не вернул мне значение, как показано на приведенных выше сайтах, пока не понятно почему :(, собственно эти функции мне и нужны

Comment: @Анонимно, я подозреваю, что вам нужны не указатели, а какая-то абстрактная структура данных типа дерева или графа. Граф и дерево на Python можно реализовать, логику работы указателей для этого на Python переносить не нужно.

Comment: @insolor, вы абсолютно правы нужно дерево, точнее список-списков (в вопросе я старался сократить код до минимума), у меня не выходит нормально запомнить элемент в первой представленной функции на Python, в ней я пытаюсь записать объект under_element, но мне надо получить значение under_element после изменения значения на 'list' используя объект element, в примере после попытки запомнить under_element, значение даже не покидает функцию, не говоря об возможности в будущем его отслеживать, я нашел выход, плохой с моей точки зрения, представленный в последнем примере, ищу выход лучше приведенного

Comment: @Анонимно, объяснение в вопросе совсем не понятное. Сложностей типа "значение не покидает функцию" тоже не понял. Если передавать в функцию список, то ничто не мешает изменить этот список внутри функции, и это изменение будет видно снаружи. Если нужно "изменить" иммутабельный объект, то логично создавать измененную копию объекта, и возвращать ее через `return` (да и и с мутабельными объектами это вполне работает).

Comment: @insolor, в примере значение element не покидает функцию, так как он переходит из mutable в unmutable (так я понимаю происходящее в функции), хотя element (при повторном "погружении" в функцию) являлся элементом element, это первая проблема функции, вторая заключается в том, что я не могу отследить изменения under_element т.к. он unmutable, по этой логике обе проблемы решаются, если выйдет отслеживать изменения неизменяемого объекта (звучит странно согласен :)), возможно можно сделать копию, которая меняется вместе с тем объектом, который она скопировала, то есть A=B, а B=A всегда

Comment: **другими словами, как возможное решение, чтобы интерпретатор менял бы второй объект при изменении первого, на то чему равен первый

Answer (score 3):

> Требуется используя адрес переменной "A" записать адрес в переменную "B", таким образом, чтобы после изменения "A", через переменную "B" можно было узнать значение в "A".

Не стоит пытаться использовать синтаксис Питона, чтобы писать на каком-то другом языке. Даже если вам удастся выразить чужие понятия, это скорее всего приведёт к неидиоматичному коду (сложному для понимания и неэффективному).

Программируя на Питоне, старайтесь мыслить в терминах Питона. В Питоне есть имена и объекты. Контейнеры содержат ссылки на другие объекты. Никаких указателей нет. [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

> Пример на С/C++:

```c
int A=0;
int *B;
B=&A;
printf("%d\n", *B); //ответ: 0
A=1;
printf("%d\n", *B); //ответ: 1
```

В Питоне целые числа неизменяемы. К примеру, вы не можете поменять значение объекта, который представляет ноль. [Присваивание целых (int) в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044)

`A = 1` в Питоне не кладёт `1` в коробку с адресом `A`. В Питоне, `A = 1` говорит, что к объекту `1` можно по имени `A` обращаться (ярлык прилепили): [Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) (на картинки посмотрите).

---

> Задача записать в список элемент так, чтобы последующие изменения этого элемента можно было увидеть через элемент списка, в который я его записал. Теоретически это поможет оптимизировать код, т.к. мне не придется искать элементы, которые я записал, проверяя все элементы в списке, т.к. я смогу сразу обращаться к нему, количество элементов произвольное количество и зависит от предустановок

Вот здесь мы к действительной проблеме приближаемся. У вас есть некоторый алгоритм, который становится неэффективным, если его механически из Си на Питон перенести. То есть это [XY-задача](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044). Вместо попыток буквального переноса Си решения, стоит рассмотреть исходную задачу (которую Си код призван был решить) и выбрать более подходящее для Питона решение -- не оглядываясь на реализации в Си. То есть необходимо привести изначальную задачу, которую вы пытались решить с помощью поиска элементов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66753/discussion-on-answer-by-jfs-----).

Answer (score 1):

Слегка модифицированный первый пример:

```
def f(element, under_element, i=0):
    print("depth=", i, "\tfs_element=", element)
    if(i<1):
        element[0] = f(element[0], under_element, i+1)
    else:
        element = under_element
    print("depth=", i, "\tff_element=", element)
    return element

element=[[0],[1]]
under_element='str'
print("start_element=", element, "\n")

f(element, under_element)

under_element='list'
print("\nfinish_element=", element)
```

Дает такой результат:

```
start_element= [[0], [1]]

depth= 0        fs_element= [[0], [1]]
depth= 1        fs_element= [0]
depth= 1        ff_element= str
depth= 0        ff_element= ['str', [1]]

finish_element= ['str', [1]]
```

Вот это:

```
under_element='str'
f(element, under_element)
under_element='list'  # хотим, чтобы 'str' внутри списка заменилось на 'list'
```

не сработает, потому что в функцию передается не указатель на переменную `under_element` (чего можно было бы добиться в Си), а значение переменной. В Python передать ссылку (или указатель) на переменную внутрь функции нет никакой возможности. Если очень захотеть, можно передать имя переменной, а потом по этому имени обратиться к глобальной переменной, но я не советовал бы так делать.

Как вариант, можно использовать "контейнерный" класс, в котором уже будет храниться значение, которое вы хотите изменять:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Container(%r)' % self.item

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)


def f(element, under_element, i=0):
    print("depth=", i, "\tfs_element=", element)
    if(i<1):
        element[0] = f(element[0], under_element, i+1)
    else:
        element = under_element
    print("depth=", i, "\tff_element=", element)
    return element

element=[[0],[1]]
under_element=Container('str')

print("start_element=", element, "\n")

f(element, under_element)

under_element.item='list'
print("\nfinish_element=", element)
```

Вывод:

```
start_element= [[0], [1]]

depth= 0        fs_element= [[0], [1]]
depth= 1        fs_element= [0]
depth= 1        ff_element= str
depth= 0        ff_element= [Container('str'), [1]]

finish_element= [Container('list'), [1]]
```

Если поменять реализацию метода `__repr__` в классе `Container`:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.item)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)
```

то формально вывод будет совпадать с требуемым:

```
start_element= [[0], [1]]

depth= 0        fs_element= [[0], [1]]
depth= 1        fs_element= [0]
depth= 1        ff_element= str
depth= 0        ff_element= ['str', [1]]

finish_element= ['list', [1]]
```

Но это не значит, что в списке хранится строка, просто класс при преобразовании в строку (например при выводе через `print`) будет "притворяться" строкой (точнее даже тем значением, которое лежит в поле `.item`, независимо от его типа). Но строковые операции с этим классом (сцепление со строкой и т.д.) не будут работать, нужно будет явно обращаться к полю `.item` объекта.

---

Еще добавлю - это все по сути попытка подтянуть низкоуровневые особенности С/С++ к Python, что изначально неправильно. Нужно исходить наоборот от реальной задачи, потом переходить к абстрактным типам данных (графы, деревья и т.д.), которые в разных языках реализуются по-разному, и дальше уже реализовывать способом идиоматичным для выбранного языка.

Comment: *можете показать или "намекнуть" как "передать имя переменной"? возможно может подойти, также буду рад, если вы скажете почему это плохой способ

Comment: *возможно я не совсем понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под передать имя переменной, а потом по этому имени обратиться к глобальной переменной

Comment: @Анонимно, плохой способ, потому что разыменование указателя в Си - быстрая операция, а обращение к элементу словаря (словаря глобальных переменных) по строковому ключу - не очень. Плюс это не универсальный способ: он будет работать с глобальными переменными, а с локальными переменными функций - нет.

Comment: Как сделать - попробуйте код `abc = 'def'; globals()['abc'] = 'qwer'; print(abc)`. Т.е. можно в принципе передавать в функцию и записывать в список имя переменной `'under_element'`, а потом при выводе списка показывать значения переменных по их именам (если они попадутся в списке). Короче, левой рукой чешем правое ухо.

Comment: @Анонимно, ну, еще вариант - хранить в отдельном списке значения, а в функцию передавать их индексы, тогда получится что список со значениями - это как бы "массив" в памяти, а индекс - указатель на элемент в этом массиве. Тоже конечно странное какое-то решение будет. Лучше просто отказаться от идеи указателей на переменные, когда пишем на Python.

Comment: спасибо, постараюсь решить эту проблему :)

Comment: @Анонимно, добавил еще пример, может такой вариант подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

`Задача записать в список элемент так, чтобы последующие изменения этого элемента можно было увидеть через элемент списка, в который я его записал.`

насколько я знаю это называется `связный список`, примеров в инете море

все остальное, что сзесь обсуждается это дичайшие велосипеды, или попытка програмирования на питоне, даже не попытавшись разобрятся как все устроено и питоне.