# Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список

Tags: python, python-faq

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,]
>>> for x in a:   x=1
>>> 
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Вопрос - почему а не равен [1,1,1,1,1]??
Неужели в цикле создается копия для каждого х?

как сделать "правильно" я понимаю. Просто интересен механизм цикла ...ведь для списка работает:

```
>>> a = [[1],[2],[3]]
>>> for x in a: x.append(33)

>>> 
>>> a
[[1, 33], [2, 33], [3, 33]]
```

а присваивание тоже "не работает" со ссылкой ...

```
>>> a
[[1, 33], [2, 33], [3, 33]]
>>> for x in a:  x = [22]

>>> 
>>> a
[[1, 33], [2, 33], [3, 33]]
>>>
```

Ладно - последние два примера, которые мне вообще кажутся странными:

```
>>> a = [[1],[2],[3]]
>>> a
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> for x in a: x = x +[11]

>>> a
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> for x in a: x+=[11]

>>> a
[[1, 11], [2, 11], [3, 11]]
>>>
```

где это и как объясняется?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Присваивание целых (int) в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Q:** Как реализован цикл `for`?

`for x in a: x = 1` можно себе представить как:

```
it = iter(a)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        x = 1
```

то есть: получить итератор из переданной коллекции и по одному обойти все элементы, присваивая каждое значение переменной `x` (это описывает поведение, не фактическую реализацию).

> **Q:** почему `а` не равен `[1,1,1,1,1]`?

`a` список содержит ссылки на самые обычные объекты. Объект никак не меняется от того, что какие-то списки могут ссылки на него содержать. Поэтому `a` не равен `[1,1,1,1,1]` по той же причине что и

```
x = 2
x = 1
```

не делает `2 == 1`. И даже если бы мы изменяемые объекты здесь использовали, такие как списки, из:

```
x = [1]
x = [2]
```

не следует, что `[1] == [2]`.

Подробнее: на первой итерации `x = next(it)` заставляет `x` имя ссылаться на тот же объект, что и `a[0]`, то есть `x is a[0]` в этот момент. Затем `x = 1` заставляет `x` имя ссылаться на единичку. Можно себе это представлять, как [ярлык с одного предмета на другой переместили](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names):

c одного объекта `a=1` [image: a1tag]  на другой объект ярлык перевесили [image: a1][image: a2tag] `a=2` . От этого изначальный объект никак не меняется, иначе даже после `for x in L: pass` у вас стал бы весь список последнему элементу равен `L = [5,5,5,5,5]`.

> два примера, которые мне вообще кажутся странными:

Для примера `a = [[1],[2],[3]]`
циклы с `x = x + [1]` против `x += [1]` неравнозначны.

Первый случай аналогичен предыдущим (простое присваивание): сумма `x + [1]` создаёт *новый* список, к которому прикрепляется имя `x` — ярлык со старого списка снимается и переносится на новый.

Второй пример использует `+=` операцию, которая для списков *по месту* изменение проводит — это равнозначно `x.extend([1])`, что не создаёт новый список, а добавляет элементы из аргумента к старому списку. В последнем случае и до и после `x` имя продолжает ссылаться на один и тот же объект (тот же список).

> где это и как объясняется?

Чтобы узнать, что `+=` делает, просто вызовите `help('+=')` в Питон REPL. Конкретно для изменяемых последовательностей (таких как списки) [поведение  `s += t` равнозначно `s.extend(t)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Answer (score 5):

Каждый раз в переменную записывается значение из списка (не копия), но при записи другого значения в эту же переменную, значение записывается именно в переменную, а не в список.

Правильно делать так:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = 1

print(a)  # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Можно удостовериться, что в переменную попадает не копия, а сам объект из списка. Только список лучше брать из чисел больше 256, т.к. для Python каждое число от -5 до 256 является одним и тем же объектом, т.е.

```
>>> a = 256
>>> b = 256
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True  # один и тот же объект

>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False  # разные объекты
```

Внимание: данное поведение не гарантируется, в разных реализациях и версиях языка внутренняя реализация объектов целых чисел может различаться.

Для примера берем числа от 1000 до 1004:

```
>>> a = list(range(1000, 1005))

>>> a
[1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]

>>> for i, x in enumerate(a):
...     print(a[i] is x)
True
True
True
True
True
```

Видим, что в переменной x каждый раз оказывается тот же объект, что и в списке по индексу.

**Обновление.**

По поводу `append`. В самом первом примере вы изменяете значение в переменной, никак не связанной со списком, по сути просто в переменную записываете новое значение (переменная сначала "указывала" на объект внутри списка, а после присваивания начала указывать на другой объект, список при этом не изменяется).

В случае с `append`, вы изменяете сам объект (его "внутренности"), полученный из списка (как я уже показал выше, при итерации по списку в переменную попадает сам объект, а не его копия). Т.к. это тот же самый объект, что лежит в списке, то видим, что и в самом списке объект меняется.

**Обновление 2**

`=` и `+=` это разные операторы, работающие по-разному. `+=` может изменять исходный объект (если объект изменяемый, например если это список, но не число, ну и в зависимости от реализации метода `__iadd__`, если это какой-то свой объект), а `=` явно заменяет значение переменной, но не изменяет объект, который лежал в переменной до присваивания.

Comment: Мне кажется, в ответе стоит как-либо упомянуть термин «ссылка»

Comment: @andreymal, я думаю не стоит, чтобы не путать с ссылками в C++, где ссылки работают совершенно не так, как переменные в Python.

Comment: Хм, кроме того, что в C++ ссылку нельзя заменить на другую, ещё какие-то отличия есть?

Comment: @andreymal, если в функцию значение передано по ссылке, то при изменении значения внутри функции значение изменится и в переменной снаружи функции. В Python такое не сработает.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за ответ... но я - хотя это и не по правилам - расширил вопрос... можете прояснить с аппендом?

Comment: @insolor Потому что в Python это так-то создание новой переменной, а не замена ссылки :) Короче, отличий между ссылками в C++ и Python нет, кроме синтаксических :)

Comment: @andreymal, в Python нет ссылок, а есть переменные. Да, по сути это ссылки, но не те ссылки, что в C++.

Comment: @insolor ну, реальную разницу между ними вы мне так и не привели ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, привел, это реальная разница.

Comment: @insolor это разница в синтаксисе, не имеющая никакого отношения к ссылкам. В питоне можно создавать новую переменную, перекрывающую старую (точнее, перекрывающую аргумент функции), а в C++ нельзя. Ссылок это никак не касается. Я продолжу считать ссылки в Python ссылками и учить всех называть их именно так :)

Comment: @andreymal, ваше право.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, дополнил ответ.

Comment: «если в функцию значение передано по ссылке, то при изменении ... значение изменится и .. снаружи функции. В Python такое не сработает. » — кстати, я тут задумался, а ведь это утверждение некорректно. И в C++, и в Python можно изменять значение по ссылке, если это значение изменяемо. В питоне неизменяемы числа, строки и.т. п., в то время как в C++ изменяемо всё. В питоне можно передать массив в функцию, и функция его может его изменить, и массив изменится и снаружи тоже. И в C++ так тоже можно. То есть разницы между ссылками опять нет, а вы ещё и вводите людей, включая меня, в заблуждение)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69392/discussion-between-insolor-and-andreymal).

Comment: Благодарю, @insolor.  последний раз дополнил вопрос ))))  получается, что интерпретатор "видя присваивание" делает запись в другой объект, создавая его на лету? Бред. Или я так и не понял...

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, ну так `=` и `+=` это разные операторы, работающие по-разному. `+=` может изменять исходный объект (если он изменяемый, например если это список, но не число, ну и в зависимости от реализации метода `__iadd__`, если это какой-то свой объект), а `=` явно заменяет значение переменной, но не изменяет объект, который лежал в переменной до присваивания.

Comment: @insolor. Да. дошло. но это как-то неожиданно... Тут надо быть начеку...

Comment: когда обсуждаете проблемы связанные с присваиванием, используйте термин "имя" вместо "переменная". В общем случае (когда проблема не относится к именно к употреблению имён  в Питоне) можно использовать менее специфичную для Питона терминологию. [Other languages have "variables"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables). Кстати, не стоит особенности реализации какой-либо специфичной версии CPython выдавать за общие факты о Питоне (кэширование -5..256 не гарантировано языком)

Comment: @andreymal: С++ чрезвычайно сложный язык, поэтому не стоит из него никакие понятия приводить. Если не упоминать C++, то слово ссылка можно использовать (спецификация Питона явно говорит, что контейнеры [такие как список] содержат ссылки).

Comment: @jfs это к insolor, он речь про C++ завёл)