# Объясните как работает цикл for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как работает цикл `for`

Пример:

```
array = [1,5,6,48,15,68,15,11,17]
for i in array:
    print(i)
```

какое значение имеет переменная `i` и почему мы вызываем её а не `array`

Comment: короткий ответ - потому что такой синтаксис `range based for`.

Comment: потому что при такой записи `for i in array` i последовательно получает значения элементов листа, а не индекс

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750868/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот цикл проходится по любому итерируемому объекту (например строке или списку), и во время каждого прохода выполняет тело цикла. Т.е. вы присваиваете к значению `i` все значения хранящиеся в `array` и выводите их в столбец.

Дополнительный пример

```
for i in 'hello world':
    print(i * 2, end='')
```

Здесь к значению `i` присваивается каждая буква из `hello word` после чего эта буква умножается на 2 и выводит все значение, а именно:

```
hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd
```

В вашем случае выведет все цифры в строку.

```
1
5
6
48
15
68
15
11
17
```

Answer (score 2):

Так же интересная возможность цикла это операция распаковки последовательности. Поскольку цикл выполнять обычное присвоение то имеет возможность выполнить множественное присвоение:

```
m = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
    ]

for a,b,c in m:
    print(a,b,c)
```

Или воспользоваться расширенной инструкцией распаковки последовательности:

```
m = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
    ]

for a,*b in m:
    print(a,b)
```