# Почему не печатает первый элемент?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]

for row in A:
    s = ' '.join(list(map(str, row)))
    print(s)      # case - 1

   #  1 2 3
   #  4 5 6


for row in A:
    s = ' '.join(list(map(str, row)))    
print(s)      # case -2

   #  4 5 6
```

Почему если  ставлю print() не в теле цикла, то печатает только последний элемент.

Comment: Мог бы напечатать только первый элемент так было бы логичнее. Но он по всей видимости начал с последнего. Почему - непонятно.

Comment: Потому вы присваиваете к `s` все значения которые были в теле `A` и т.к. значение менялись последнее значение которое было и выводится. Так же про [`for` здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766954/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for/766961#766961)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравните Ваш код с вот этим:

```
A = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]
s=""
for row in A:
    s = s+" ".join(list(map(str, row)))+"\n"
print(s)
# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6
```

Надеюсь, разница даст ответ на ваш вопрос.