# Случайная выборка, используя отбор с заменой. Как упростить код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

```
array = []
import random
for i in range(10):
    i = i + 1
    random_number = random.randint(1,100)
    array.append(random_number)
    while i == 10:
        break
if i == 10:
    print(array)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, упростить код. После заполнения масива на 10 значений надо напечатать это массив. Желательно без использования оператора if.

Используется Python 3.5

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Различия между циклами for и while](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790505/Различия-между-циклами-for-и-while)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Объясните как работает цикл for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766954/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for/766961#766961)

Comment: спасибо, всем за ответы!

Answer (score 2):

Подытожим все сказанное и не сказанное: (учитывая, что Вы видимо, новичок, начнем по-порядку):

1. Как подметил @insolor: не нужно увеличивать переменную `i` на единицу каждый раз, она и так будет увеличиваться.
2. Нужды в цикле `while` нет, цикл `for` сам завершить после 10 итераций («повторений» если проще выражаться). И в конструкции `if` тоже нет смысла — вполне логично, что после завершения цикла переменная `i` будет равна 10: тут просто без вариантов.

Т.е. код можно упростить до такого:

```
array = []
import random
for i in range(10):
    random_number = random.randint(1,100)
    array.append(random_number)
print(array)
```

Далее, есть такая вещь как «Генераторы списков», если Вы не знаете, что это Вам стоит почитать об этом, это не сложно.

Простой пример генераторов списков:

```
array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 98, 123, 45]
# % — операция вычисления остатка от деления 
# если остаток от деления на 2 равен единице, то число нечетно
only_odd_numbers = [n for n in array if n % 2 == 1]
print(only_odd_numbers ) # [1, 5, 123, 45]
```

С помощью генераторов списка можно еще больше упростить код:

```
import random
array = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(10)]
print(array)
```

**UPDATE:**

Есть еще такая функция как `random.choices`. Суть этой функции на примерах:

```
import random
arr1 = random.choices([1, 2], k=10)
arr2 = random.choices(range(1, 10))
arr3 = random.choices(range(1, 100), k=10)
arr4 = random.choices(range(1, 10), k=20)

print(arr1)  # [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]
print(arr2)  # [8]
print(arr3)  # [60, 35, 80, 26, 7, 65, 58, 9, 77, 2]
print(arr4)  # [1, 1, 6, 4, 2, 6, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 7, 8, 3, 5, 3]
```

Обратите внимание: `arr1` содержит только единицы и двойки.

Таким образом: `random.choices` возвращает список, состоящий из определенного количества (определяемого параметром `k`) элементов, каждый из которых является случайным элементом последовательности, которую мы передали в первом аргументе.

**UPDATE** Важно замечание сделал @jfs: «`randint` включает правую границу, а `range` — нет»

Comment: обратите внимание randint включает правую границу, а range — нет. `random.choices(range(1,101),k=10)`

Answer (score 1):

У вас в любом случае список заполняется 10-ю значениями, поэтому `if` не нужен. Просто выводите список с помощью `print` после цикла.

Что еще **не** нужно:

- `i = i + 1` т.к. `i` и так как у вас в цикле `i` и так на каждой итерации автоматически становится на 1 больше.
- `while` с `break` внутри цикла `for` в данном случае не имеет смысла. Цикл `for` и так закончит выполнение после 10 итераций. Просто уберите `while`.

Итого остается:

```
import random

array = []

for i in range(10):
    random_number = random.randint(1,100)
    array.append(random_number)

print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не изобретайте велосипед, в Python всё включено:

```
import random
random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
```

`range(from, to)` вернёт итератор на множество целых чисел от `from` до `to` с шагом 1, а `sample(population, k)` выберет `k` случайных элементов из множества `population`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: Если человек еще не понимает как работает цикл `for` и другие базовые конструкции языка, то итераторам его учить как-то рановато.

Comment: В вашем решении есть одна проблема, в данном случае, конечно все хорошо, но что если нужен массив из 1000 случайных чисел между 0 и 9? `random.sample` возвращает только список из уникальных элементов.

Comment: Вы правы, конечно. Но, как говорится, "без нормального ТЗ результат будет ХЗ". ТЗ было "упростите код, желательно без if", результат ему полностью удовлетворяет. Никаких требований к качеству сгенерированных чисел предъявлено не было. Зато на момент написания этого комментария у ТСа есть целых 3 (не считая его собственного) варианта решения его задачи.

Comment: В принципе, да, Вы правы. Но ожидать нормального ТЗ от человека только начинающего учить Python, согласитесь, вряд ли стоит.