# Про циклы for в Python: Почему второй цикл for переоценивается на другое значение икса?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, есть следующий код:

```
x = 4
for i in range(x):
    for k in range(x):
        print(k)
        x = 2
```

Печатает:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

Почему второй цикл for переоценивается на другое значение икса? Несмотря на то, что это значение находится в его теле. Однако, если написать такой же код, но с одним циклом, аналогичного переоценивания нет:

```
x = 4
for k in range(x):
        print(k)
        x = 2
```

Печатает:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: что  значит "переоценивается" ?

Comment: То есть значение х изменяется с 4 на 2, потому что других причин, что код пишет 01 я не знаю

Comment: Вы меняете значение "глобальной" переменной `x` с 4 на 2. Оно, что характерно, меняется: ваш код работает штатно. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Вы во вложенном цикле присвоили `x = 2`. После того как вложенный цикл завершился, выполняется вторая итерация внешнего цикла. Теперь строка `for k in range(x):` рассматривается заново и второй раз вложенный цикл выполняется с `x` равным  2.

Comment: А почему тогда в случае с одним циклом, изменение значения икса не влияет?

Comment: количество итераций цикла рассчитывается при первом его выполнении. В первоначальном примере количество итераций вложенного цикла рассчитывается заново при каждой итерации внешнего цикла. По выводу вы можете увидеть, что внешний цикл по прежнему выполнил 4 итерации, в то время как внутренний первый раз сделал 4 итерации, а потом 3 раза по 2 итерации.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750868/23044)

Answer (score 4):

`range(x)` выражение вычисляется ровно один раз для каждого цикла. В первом случае у вас четыре раза вычисляется `range(x)` при создании вложенного цикла. Во втором случае у вас ровно один цикл — изменения `x` после вычисления `range(x)` никакого влияния на уже созданный range объект не оказывают.

Answer (score 4):

Если добавить промежуточные переменные, то становится очевиден порядок создания объектов и использования значений

```
x = 4
range4 = range(x)   # x == 4
for i in range4:
    range2 = range(x)   # x == 4 на первой итерации, на остальных x == 2
    for k in range2:
        print(k)
        x = 2
```

Comment: То есть если циклы выполняются поочередно (сначала внешний, потом внутренний), то получается, что программа запоминает два разных значений икса? Для внешней ничего не меняется и икс равен 4, а во внутреннем икс после второй итерации равен 2

Comment: Цикл не запоминает значение икса. Цикл работает с объектом, созданным на базе значения икса, в данном случае - списками длины 4 или 2. Длина уже созданного списка не меняется при изменении значения х. 

То есть 

(1) сперва x = 4 
(2) создали список А, в нём 4 объекта. И бежим по этому списку.
(3) задали x = 2
(4) список А от этого никак не изменится, останется какой был
(5) при создании нового списка используется новое значение х, и получается список содержащий 2 объекта.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение!