# почему не обновляется list c помощью filter

Tags: list, python-2.x, filter

Есть список списков строк data, требуется удалить пустые

```
for line in data:
    line = filter(None, line)
```

не работает

Пример data:

```
['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', '', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process', '', '']
['as', 'cat', 'simply', 'catenates', 'streams', 'of', 'bytes', '', 'it', 'can', 'be', 'also', 'used', 'to', 'concatenate', 'binary', 'files', '', 'where', 'it', 'will', 'just', 'concatenate', 'sequence', 'of', 'bytes', '', '']
['a', 'common', 'interactive', 'use', 'of', 'cat', 'for', 'a', 'single', 'file', 'is', 'to', 'output', 'the', 'content', 'of', 'a', 'file', 'to', 'standard', 'output', '', '']
```

Comment: Вы что удалить хотите? Пустые **списки** или пустые **строки**?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750868/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time


data = [['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', '', 'cats', 'have', 'not',
         'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication',
         'process', '', ''],

        ['as', 'cat', 'simply', 'catenates', 'streams',
         'of', 'bytes', '', 'it', 'can', 'be', 'also', 'used', 'to',
         'concatenate', 'binary', 'files', '', 'where', 'it', 'will', 'just',
         'concatenate', 'sequence', 'of', 'bytes', '', ''],

        ['a', 'common',
         'interactive', 'use', 'of', 'cat', 'for', 'a', 'single', 'file', 'is',
         'to', 'output', 'the', 'content', 'of', 'a', 'file', 'to', 'standard',
         'output', '', '']]

begin = time.clock()
for lst in data:
     result = list(filter(bool, lst))
     print(result)
print("\nlist(filter(bool, lst)): speed {}\n".format((time.clock() - begin)))

begin = time.clock()
for lst in data:
     result = list(filter(None, lst))
     print(result)
print("\nlist(filter(None, lst)): speed {}\n".format((time.clock() - begin)))

begin = time.clock()
for lst in data:
     result = list(filter(len, lst))
     print(result)
print("\nlist(filter(len, lst)): speed {}\n".format((time.clock() - begin)))

begin = time.clock()
for lst in data:
     result = list(filter(lambda item: item, lst))
     print(result)
print("\nlist(filter(lambda item: item, lst)): speed {}\n".format((time.clock() - begin)))
```

Результаты

```
['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process']
['as', 'cat', 'simply', 'catenates', 'streams', 'of', 'bytes', 'it', 'can', 'be', 'also', 'used', 'to', 'concatenate', 'binary', 'files', 'where', 'it', 'will', 'just', 'concatenate', 'sequence', 'of', 'bytes']
['a', 'common', 'interactive', 'use', 'of', 'cat', 'for', 'a', 'single', 'file', 'is', 'to', 'output', 'the', 'content', 'of', 'a', 'file', 'to', 'standard', 'output']

list(filter(bool, lst)): speed 6.0000000000001025e-05

['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process']
['as', 'cat', 'simply', 'catenates', 'streams', 'of', 'bytes', 'it', 'can', 'be', 'also', 'used', 'to', 'concatenate', 'binary', 'files', 'where', 'it', 'will', 'just', 'concatenate', 'sequence', 'of', 'bytes']
['a', 'common', 'interactive', 'use', 'of', 'cat', 'for', 'a', 'single', 'file', 'is', 'to', 'output', 'the', 'content', 'of', 'a', 'file', 'to', 'standard', 'output']

list(filter(None, lst)): speed 3.799999999999984e-05

['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process']
['as', 'cat', 'simply', 'catenates', 'streams', 'of', 'bytes', 'it', 'can', 'be', 'also', 'used', 'to', 'concatenate', 'binary', 'files', 'where', 'it', 'will', 'just', 'concatenate', 'sequence', 'of', 'bytes']
['a', 'common', 'interactive', 'use', 'of', 'cat', 'for', 'a', 'single', 'file', 'is', 'to', 'output', 'the', 'content', 'of', 'a', 'file', 'to', 'standard', 'output']

list(filter(len, lst)): speed 3.900000000000084e-05

['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process']
['as', 'cat', 'simply', 'catenates', 'streams', 'of', 'bytes', 'it', 'can', 'be', 'also', 'used', 'to', 'concatenate', 'binary', 'files', 'where', 'it', 'will', 'just', 'concatenate', 'sequence', 'of', 'bytes']
['a', 'common', 'interactive', 'use', 'of', 'cat', 'for', 'a', 'single', 'file', 'is', 'to', 'output', 'the', 'content', 'of', 'a', 'file', 'to', 'standard', 'output']
```

---

Вверух показал все рабочие варианты, что бы обновить **data** нужно обратится к его элеметам и обновить.

```
for indx, item in enumerate(data):
     data[indx] = list(filter(bool, item))

print(data)
```

Comment: не по существу , мб , я не правильно сформулировал вопрос, но меня не интересовала скорость , и факт того что фильтрует я тоже проверил конечно же, а меня интересовала как обновлять лист data сразу по ходу фильтрации , возможно тут нужен какой-нибудь то итератор??

Comment: @sergosar вам нужно обновить каждый список. Смотрите обновленный ответ.