# Команда print стала переменной - как исправить? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.5

Добрый день!

Каким-то мистическим образом команда print стала переменной, в результате чего невозможно её использовать для вывода информации. Как исправить?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Стала переменной, видимо, в результате присваивания `print = 20`. Исправить - `del print`.

Comment: Да! Гениально! Спасибо!

Comment: если хотите вернуть одолжение человеку, который  `print=20` выполнил,  можете изменить константу, например  так чтобы [`(32+10)==32`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571515/23044). При особой зловредности можно в PYTHONSTARTUP прописать код.