# Почему присвоенная переменная "зависит" другой переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код:

```
a = {"1": "2", "3":"4"}
b = a
print(a, b)
b['1'] = "5"
print(a, b)
```

Почему в конце выводит `{"1": "5", "3":"4"}` это значение перемененной а

`{"1": "5", "3":"4"}` а это значение переменной b. Так вот почему когда изменилось значение переменной b то и изменилось значение переменной a?
Может это я не прав, может так должно быть. Но если я не ошибаюсь, то b это копия a.

Comment: b это ссылка на массив, и a это ссылка. И они указывают в одно место

Comment: как я понимаю, в питоне переменные - это ссылки на объекты, чтоб создать новый, а не передать ссылку, для списков самое простое сделать слайс b = a[:]. А для словаря dic2 = dic1.copy()

Comment: связанный вопрос [Присваивание целых (int) в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b = a` заставляет имя `b` ссылаться на *тот же* объект что и `a` имя, то есть `a is b`.  [Один объект — два имени](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names).

`b = a` никогда не копирует. Чтобы создать новый словарь, с теми же ключами, значениями:

```
b = dict(a)
```

В этом случае `b['a'] = '5'` изменяет новый словарь, не трогая исходный словарь.  В общем случае,  контейнеры могут определять `.copy()` метод.

`b` это поверхностная копия, то есть сами ключи и значения не копируются, к примеру, `a['3'] is b['3']`. Чтобы создать копию и вложенных объектов рекурсивно:

```
import copy

c = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = {"1": "2", "3":"4"}  
b = a                         # переменная b ссылается на тот же словарь
a is b                        # True
```

Чтобы b ссылался на другой объект можно сделать `copy`:

```
a = {"1": "2", "3":"4"} 
b= b.copy()
a is b                        # False
```

или так

```
a = {"1": "2", "3":"4"}
b = {"1": "2", "3":"4"}
a is b                        # False
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что, когда Вы пишете `b = a`, то не создаете новый словарь, а создаете новую ссылку на уже существующий словарь. a и b начинают указывать на один и тот же объект словаря.

Answer (score 0):

Обе переменные являются ссылками на один объект, так как словарь - изменяемый объект. Так же будет и со списками.

Comment: Даже если бы словарь был неизменяемым, переменные всё равно являлись бы ссылками на один объект. Как-то коряво ответ сформулирован

Comment: Если бы они были строками или большими одинаковыми числами, то они бы указывали на разные объекты.

Comment: Ничего подобного. `a = 99**99; b = a; print(a is b)` печатает `True`. Напомню, `is` возвращает `True`, если сравниваемые вещи являются одним и тем же объектом (не просто равными объектами, а именно одним и тем же)

Comment: @andreymal, для справки - для маленьких чисел (<= 256) Python кеширует целые числа и `a = 200; b = 200; a is b` вернет `True`