# python из списка в словарь

Tags: python

Имеется словарик:

```
item = {
'title': '',
'photo': [],
'location': '',
```

}

Затем его использует другой словарик:

```
user = {
'item': item,
'list': []
```

}

Затем последний редактируется в ходе выполнения скрипта:

```
user['item']['title'] = 'Title'
```

В итоге изменяются оба словаря, а как сделать чтобы первый оставался нетронутым?

Comment: Не «оба словаря», а это один-единственный словарь, ссылки на который расположились в двух местах. Делайте копию словаря. Если вам нужно, чтобы для списка `'photo': []` тоже сделалась копия, используйте deepcopy. https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-copy.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему присвоенная переменная “зависит” другой переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769881/204271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В питоне в переменных хранятся не сами объекты, а ссылки на них. И в данном случае тоже, то есть, `item` - это ссылка на тот же словарь, что и `user['item']`. И если вы меняете объект по одной ссылке, то на по второй ссылке он, как можно понять, изменится тоже. Если хотите избежать этого - используйте метод словаря `dict.copy` или `copy.deepcopy`. А ещё есть слово `is`, которое проверяет, ведут ли две ссылки на один и тот же объект.

```
>>> first = {'title': '', 'photo': [], 'location': ''}
>>> second = first
>>> second is first
True
>>> second = first.copy()
>>> second == first
True
>>> second is first
False
```

Но лучше используйте `deepcopy`, он копирует и вложенные списки.

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> arr = [[[1], [1,2,3,4]], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
>>> arr2 = arr
>>> arr2 is arr
True
>>> arr_copied = arr.copy()
>>> arr_copied is arr
False
>>> arr_copied[0] is arr[0]
True
>>> arr_deepcopied = deepcopy(arr)
>>> arr_deepcopied == arr
True
>>> arr_deepcopied is arr
False
>>> arr_deepcopied[0] is arr[0]
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто делать копию item, чтобы они стали разными объектами:

```
item = {
  'title': '',
  'photo': [],
  'location': '',}

user = {
  'item': dict(item),
  'list': []}

user['item']['title'] = 'Title'
print(item)
{'title': '', 'photo': [], 'location': ''}
```