# Словарь заполняется одинаковыми значениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, xlrd

У меня есть таблица, откуда я беру информацию и заполняю все словари, однако, в итоге почему-то все словари имеют одинаковые значения. Как это исправить? Почему это происходит?

```py
book = xlrd.open_workbook("1k.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
num_cols = sheet.ncols
num_rows = sheet.nrows
groups_list = []
for col_index in range(num_cols):
    group_cell = str(sheet.cell(1, col_index).value)
    if "-18" in group_cell:
        groups_list.append(group_cell)
groups_list = dict.fromkeys(groups_list, [
        dict.fromkeys(["ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК", "ВТОРНИК", "СРЕДА", "ЧЕТВЕРГ", "ПЯТНИЦА", "СУББОТА"], dict.fromkeys(["1 пара", "2 пара", "3 пара", "4 пара", "5 пара", "6 пара"], dict.fromkeys(["Предмет", "Преподаватель", "Аудитория", "Вид занятия"]))),
        dict.fromkeys(["ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК", "ВТОРНИК", "СРЕДА", "ЧЕТВЕРГ", "ПЯТНИЦА", "СУББОТА"], dict.fromkeys(["1 пара", "2 пара", "3 пара", "4 пара", "5 пара", "6 пара"], dict.fromkeys(["Предмет", "Преподаватель", "Аудитория", "Вид занятия"])))])

for col_index in range(num_cols):
    for group in groups_list.keys():
        if group == str(sheet.cell(1, col_index).value):
            row_index = 3
            for day, couples in groups_list[group][0].items():
                for couple in couples.keys():
                    groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Предмет'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value)
                    groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Вид занятия'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index+1).value)
                    groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Преподаватель'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index+2).value)
                    groups_list[group][0][day][couple]['Аудитория'] = str(sheet.cell(row_index, col_index+3).value)
                    row_index += 2
```

Если выводить информацию в самом последнем цикле, то вся информация заполняется правильно, однако, если вывести словари в других циклах или вне циклов, то будет выводиться неверная информация

Comment: Т.е. одинаковые предметы, вид занятия, преподаватель и аудитория?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему присвоенная переменная “зависит” другой переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769881/204271)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что из-за fromkeys все ключи имеют одну ссылку